# Recoger datos JSON de servidor externo después de POST (Fetch?)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

EDITO e intento explicarme mejor:

https://www.iconcox.com/api/jimiApi.html
Estoy usando esta API con los datos que me han suministrado

Veo que necesito enviar por POST los parámetros a su servidor a la siguiente URL como dice la documentación.

> Request URL
> The unique request URL is: http://open.10000track.com/route/rest
>
> Different interfaces are identified by request parameter method.

Entonces mi forma para comprobar que funciona enviar un formulario con el action hacia ese servidor por POST, de la siguiente manera.

```
<h1>jimi.device.location.get (Recibir ubicación)</h1>
<form action="http://open.10000track.com/route/rest" method="POST">
    <!-- Parámetros comunes -->
    <input type="text" name="method" id="method" value="jimi.device.location.get"><br>
    <input type="text" name="timestamp" value="<?php echo $timestamp ?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="app_key" value="<?php echo $app_key ?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="sign" value="<?php echo $sign ?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="sign_method" value="<?php echo $sign_method ?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="v" value="<?php echo $v ?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="format" value="<?php echo $format ?>"><br>
    <!-- Valores dependen del método -->
    <input type="text" name="access_token" value="<?php echo $access_token ?>"><br>
    <input type="text" name="imeis" value="<?php echo $imei_1 ?>, <?php echo $imei_2?>"><br>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Al enviar este formulario me lleva a la servidor del proveedor y me muestra un JSON con los datos que le he pedido enviando el formulario, en este caso la ubicación.

[image: Captura de pantalla]

Lo que intento hacer es cómo podría almacenar los datos que devuelve el servidor del proveedor para guardarlos en un JSON propio, lo que he leído es hacer una petición por AJAX y guardar el request (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) pero no tengo claro si es lo que necesito o cómo lo puedo ejecutar.

Gracias

Comment: No eres nuevo, sabes que sin código va a ser muy difícil ayudarte. Edita la pregunta y agrega el código con la petición que haces, así como un ejemplo del resultado que devuelve.

Comment: Tendras que usar una base de datos con ciertas tablas relacionadas que te permitan almacenar la informacion del `JSON` por columnas, o por lo menos yo lo haria asi, yo no guardaria el `JSON` como tal en la base de datos, si no que mas bien guardaria esa informacion haciendo una tabla especializada sobre esos campos del `JSON`, aunque si tu `JSON` es demasiado largo o tiene demasiados campos, ahi si consideraria la posibilidad de guardar todo el `JSON` como un string en la base de datos.

Comment: Eso va a depender de la tecnologia que uses en el backend de tu api rest. esa misma estructura JSON que estas enviando se debe poder recuperar del cuerpo de la petición. request.body.xxx. Aqui veo que marcas PHP como lenguaje, entonces deberias estar buscando en esta variable $_POST['xxx'].
Pero como te dice [Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby) faltan detalles en tu pregunta.

Comment: Finalmente he actualizado explicando lo mejor que puedo, gracias

Comment: Creo que hacer esto por Javascript es un paso innecesario, porque desde PHP puedes enviar la petición directamente con cURL. Aquí un ejemplo básico, antiguo, pero te puede servir de guía: https://voragine.net/weblogs/como-hacer-una-peticion-post-a-un-servidor-usando-curl-en-un-script-php